# Какую букву необходимо использовать в предложении?

Tags: орфография

Здравствуйте.
Интересует вопрос: в предложении "кем мы будем когда вырастем?" слово "вырастем" пишется через "е" или через "и" в конце?
(Вопросительное предложение написано в контексте вопроса детей к себе, а не подразумевает выращивание чего-либо).
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Кем мы будем, когда вырастем?-вырастем, потому что вырасти - 1 спр., не на -ить.А вот если б было вырастить - 2 спр., на -ить Вырастить что-то, кого-то.

Answer (score 0):

Вырасти -  глагол 1 спряжения, поэтому окончание "ем". Есть еще одно правило, которое касается глаголов с приставкой "вы". У этих глаголов приставочный глагол пишется так же, как бесприставочный: РАСТЁМ, поэтому ВЫРАСТЕМ

Answer (score 0):

Кем мы будем , когда вырастим тунеядца? Кем мы будем, когда вырастем и станем взрослыми?

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос не то чтобы интересный... Скорее уж искуственно подзапутанный. Не настолько, правда, чтобы приковать к себе какое-то особое внимание. Тем более, на эту тему мы где-то совсем недавно говорили.

Вырастим (кого? - в значении  "взрастим") возможно только с явным или очевидным по контексту указанием на это "кого": dырастим детей, урожай, смену. В Вашей фразе этого нет и не подразумевается.

Поэтому - ***вырастем***. Без вариантов и особых сомнений.